# Am I computing the left and right cosets of this subgroup properly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I am presented with the following problem:

Let $H = \{(), (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$ be a sugroup of $A_4$ (alternating group on $4$ elements), where $()$ is the identity permutation.

Find the left cosets of $H$.

**My solution**:

First off, I identified all the elements in $A_4$: $(1), (13)(24), (14)(23), (12)(34), (124), (132), (123), (134), (124), (143), (234), (243)$

Then, since the group operation is permutation multiplication, then we can write every element in the left coset as:

$\{ah \, \, | \,\, a \in A_4, h \in H \}$

Therefore we have:

1. (1)()
2. (1)(12)(34)
3. (1)(13)(24)
4. (1)(124)

Eventually applying the last element of $A_4$ on $H$, we have:

1. (243)
2. (243)(12)(34)
3. (243)(13)(24)

And so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct (although you're missing an element for the so-called "last" coset; also, it's a good idea to simplify permutations). Well done.

You should get $|A_4|/|H|=(4!/2)/4=3$ left cosets.

Comment: So the total should be 3 left cosets because a lot of the cosets in the form I wrote are actually duplicates of each other, right?

Comment: Yes, @JustinTrudeau.

Comment: Does the formula |A_4|/|H| also apply to the cardinality of right cosets?

Comment: Yes, @JustinTrudeau.